# custom wordpress blog to suite my web style

Tags: wordpress

I installed wordpress for blog publish.
but it is the default temple of wordpress.
Is there a way/tutorial to customize wordpress to fit the style of a web site?

Your comment welcome

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can definitely customize your website. There are lots of way to do that.

> We will create a child theme, make modifications to the style.css file, the functions.php file, child theme template files, introduce you to theme hooks, and more.

[Read This For Customizing Your Wordpress Blog](http://www.presscoders.com/wordpress-theme-customization-guide/)

Also you can make your own theme or you may choose the suitable theme [Here](https://wordpress.org/themes/)

Hope it helps.